# Find for .lnk files on a device

Tags: c#, console

How can I find .lnk files using C# on a device (USB) and then delete them?, I did this, but doesn't detect any .lnk files:

```
string dir = @"device:\*.lnk";
string dirt = dir.Replace("device", dev.ToLower());
if (File.Exists(dirt))
{
    Console.Write("lnk files found, deleting them");
    File.Delete(dirt);
    Console.Write("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
{
    Console.Write("No lnk files found");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the files by extension use can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://Directory.GetFiles) method.
Example:

```
 string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk");
```